# Android - skia decoder->decode returned false

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am attempting to upload an image to a mysql database as a blob and then download that image to be displayed in an ImageView. The code I'm using to encode the image using Base64 is:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
screen.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and the code I'm using to display the image after it has been downloaded is:

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.URL_SAFE);
currentImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

I've tried some solutions other people have posted including the use of the FlushedInputStream. Does anyone have any ideas?